# django view for http://127.0.0.1:8000/

Tags: django-views

I've already searched for my topic but the results were showed fixes for e.g. 127.0.0.1:8000/polls, 127.0.0.1:8000/app_xy etc. but nor for 127.0.0.1:8000 direct.
I want my Homepage show view-result e. g. "This is my homepage" if I call it with 127.0.0.1:8000
My idea is to edit my website's main-urls.py (myWebsite/urls.py) with the following line:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^$', <no idea what to do here>),

url(r'^app2/', include('app2.urls')),
url(r'^polls/', include('polls.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

]

I created a view (myWebsite/views.py) which contains:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def index(request):
     return HttpResponse('Hello from the Homepage')
```

I had no problems with the views of the apps (app2, polls) and they work fine, but I don't know how to call the view above from the main-urls.py. Or what do you advise me to do?

I hope I explained my problem well enough.

Thx for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I'm a little advanced now, I am going to answer my question on my own:

The solution is to add the following to make an import of the views and put an URL to the project's urls.py:

```
from first_app import views
```

and add the urlpatterns:

```
urlpatterns = [
... ,
url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
]
```

If you go to your browser and connect to http://127.0.0.1:8000/ you will see the result:

> Hello from the Homepage

This is a simple respond of the index-function in the views.py. Instead of this you better create a template (e. g. home.html) and render this in the index-function.